# Need to list files under a specific folder in a main folder using java

Tags: java, file, directory

I need to get all the files under the "completed jobs" folder and my main level is "jobs" and i want to filter all the files under the "completed jobs" folder

```
  http://192.168.0.19/svn/cadgraf/Branch/Jobs
     user1
    Active
    Completedobs

 user2
    Active
    Completedjobs

 user3
    Active
    CompletedJobs
```

i used this to find all the files in job folder:

```
   public File[] listf(String directoryName) throws IOException {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        try {
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().contains(".xml")) {
                fileNameList.addElement(file.getName());
                files.add(file);
                l_storieslist.setModel(fileNameList);

            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return fList;
}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having and how have you tried to solve it? How do your actual results differ from your expected results?

Comment: I see that you have edited your post. What problem are you having? Do you have a question? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Do you want to keep only the files in "completed jobs", or all files except those in "completed jobs"?

Comment: I need to get all the files inside completed jobs folders....

Comment: Ok, so I assume you also want files in subfolders of completed jobs? Otherwise, I can't see why your code doesn't already do what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation for File.listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29).

Note that listFiles will give you both files and folders, since folders are just regarded as a different kind of files. If you want only files, not folders, use the [isFile() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29).

To get all files in a folder and all subfolders, you can (1) add folders to a list and files to another list (and removing the folder from the folder list after you looked through it), and (2) do that for every folder until the folder list is empty.

You can also [give a file filter to the listFiles method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29), and then create a filter that lets through files and one filter that lets through folders. However, for such a simple problem that might just be more confusing than useful.